# Alkoxide as a leaving group in hydrolysis of ester

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrolysis

In the base catalysed hydrolysis the hydroxide ion adds to the ester to form a tetrahedral intermediate, after which the alkoxide ions leave and forms carboxylate ion and alcohol.
Also we find the rate of reaction to be quite high.
So my questions are:

1. Most importantly, alkoxide is a very strong base. So why is it acting as a leaving group here (apparently, a very good leaving group due to the high rate of reaction)?
2. Why is the tertrahedral intermediate not as stable as the corresponding ones of carbonyl compounds?
3. Why is this reaction essentially irreversible, considering the fact that alkoxide is a stronger base the hydroxide ion? (Therefore it should be able to displace the hydroxide in the hypothetical backward reaction.)

Comment: It is irreversible because the alkoxide deprotonates the carboxylic acid wihich is the initial product of the hydrolysis.

Comment: @Waylander So,why can't the carboxylate anion once again take up a proton either from the aqueous phase, or from the alcohol, because we have seen earlier in the mechanism scheme of this reaction only the alkoxide can be removed as a leaving group?

Comment: For (2), tetrahedral intermediates with a leaving group are not stable. Not sure what corresponding ones you're talking about, but those are probably not stable.

Comment: @YUSUFHASAN It can, but the proton on it is the most acidic (its an acid after all) so it is the most likely to be removed in a system where protons are being exchanged between all the species present.

Comment: @Waylander But,what I really want to know is related to (1), why is the alkoxide even leaving in the first place? Because,if such a bad leaving group is being removed,then it seems to me that after a few unsuccessful collisions, a protonated carboxylic acid can be formed, and the alkoxide can initiate a reverse reaction which may soon become favourable under thermodynamic control.

Comment: @Waylander In fact, I have had this doubt since we started studying esters and their reactions in our class: **why does the alkoxide leave with such a great rate(we were told it is fast) in nucleophilic acyl substitution?** It occurs in various places: Claisen condensation(attack of the deprotonated ester on the other) and this hydrolysis reaction,to name a few. I am not at all convinced by the these mechanisms where we remove the alkoxide after addition to the carbonyl, can you please explain this anomaly(apparently) to me?

Comment: @Zhe What the OP is referring to are the intermediates formed by the addition of,say, a Grignard reagent to carbonyl compound. Here, we can give answer as a Td complex of the form O-MgX+ before the aqueous workup to create an alcohol,but in case of esters, we have got to remove the alkoxide when the Grignard reagent is added even before the aq. workup, and we cannot give the answer as an O-MgX+ intermediate(at least in the questions we do;I know the OP personally,so I know what he is referring to), why is this so? **You say Td intermediate with leaving grp aren't stable,is OR- a leaving grp?**

Comment: @YUSUFHASAN here's the thing; primary and secondary alkoxides are not substantially worse leaving groups than OH -. What makes the reaction proceed is that it is irreversible. OH- adds and leaves again many times but that is a dead end because it regenerates SM.

Comment: @Waylander But in my O.chem book, they have given a statement as Cl- reacting with R-OR'(an ether) will **not** give R'-Cl and OR- because "OR- is a strong base and so, a poor leaving group", what about this?

Comment: @Waylander Please address this issue of leaving group capacity(or lack of it) of alkoxide in a detailed answer if it is possible, because both me and the OP are highly confused about the very fundamentals of esters reactions,in particular, nucleophilic acyl substitution(also,if it possible, could you talk about the attack of an enolate attacking on a second ester and eliminating alkoxide in the Claisen condensation?)

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/72456/ro-alkoxide-as-a-leaving-group https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41331/why-does-a-carbonyl-reform-in-ester-reactions

Comment: @ YUSUF HASAN: A good way to appreciate how tetrahedral alkoxide intermediates collapse is to look at the pKa of the possible leaving groups. In saponification, alkoxide eliminates RO- whose conjugate acid is ROH (pKa ~16) as opposed to eliminating RCH2- (conjugate acid RCH3 (pKa 50). The tetrahedral intermediate is not stable. Adding RMgBr to R'(C=O)R" forms RR'R"CO-. It stops here, it is stable, with no elimination (RH, R'H, RH" pKa ~50) until protonation.

Comment: @user55119 But what about the example I cited in comment 9 above? Why does alkoxide not leave then? Or,to put it in other words, why does the Td complex **have** to collapse, when the potential leaving groups are alkoxide and R-?I normally don't request an answer on the SE network as I am aware of the policies,but I would like to make an exception here,and probably go out of my way to request you to provide an answer if it is possible,depicting conclusively where the alkoxide can or cannot act as a leaving group, and why do esters have an uncanny tendency to hydrolyse in basic medium. Thanks!